# How to send correctly an unsigned long byte with Arduino?

Tags: c, arduino-uno, serial-communication

I am testing the serial communication with Arduino like this:

```
  timeStamp = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  Serial.flush();   
  Serial.write((uint8_t*)timeStamp, 4)
```

On the other side, I am reading this byte with `read(fd, &rx, 4)` in a C program. I expect to read always the same value, but instead of reading `0xffffffff` I have `0x370066bf` so there is a problem with decoding. Ps: I have set the serial port to read raw bytes, so there are no dedicated bytes to encode carriage return or other special characters.

Comment: You need to post both sending and receiving code, and provide a lot more data about both platforms.  For example, what does value does `read()` actually return?  I strongly suspect you're ignoring the actual return value from `read()` and just expecting it to work.

Comment: You need to be confident the hello world test is working. Send some strings and read chars in a loop and print them. Does this work? Has the cable fallen out?

Comment: Perhaps use a terminal software on PC end. You need to typically disable hardware/software flow control. Sending chars would be easy to test.

Comment: Do you check the return from read? Is it reading 4 bytes? Perhaps set rx to a know value before as a belt and braces.

Comment: Oh! you send FFFFFF and get junk. This smells of baud rate. Again use a terminal app with flow control turned off. Send Hello World repeatedly and fiddle with term setting until it starts appearing properly. Then make you app with the read do the same.

Comment: I think Putty will work as a serial terminal. This will help.

Comment: What is **`unsigned long byte`** as have not heard about it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that your `Serial.write((uint8_t*)timeStamp, 4)` always sends 4 bytes from memory starting with address `0xFFFFFFFF`. This is because `timeStamp` is not a pointer, but you cast it to a pointer. Please try casting the address of `timeStamp` instead: `Serial.write(((uint8_t*)(&timeStamp)), 4);` and see if that works.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, and that there are no serious issues related to baud, hw/sw flow control, etc, like the guys mentioned in the comments to your question. 
I would make a small checklist based on those comments for use in future with serial comm, since they make very good points. 

The reason I saw the missing & is because I've done the same typo on some occasions (once bitten, twice shy) :) .